# Why is my vanilla JS code slower than jQuery equivalent and how to profile it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, profiling

after using heavily jQuery, I have found out, that some basic operations are much faster in vanilla JS (duh!) and therefore better to write in pure JS than using heavyweight jQuery for everything.

But sometimes vanilla JS is slower and sometimes slower a lot than equivalent in jQuery. Right now, I have this scenario. JQuery's delegated .on() function against my simple version. As my code is much simpler and is doing "less things" I was expecting the result to be in favor of vanilla JS. But using JSPerf I see that my code is 60%+ slower. Code example below.

Can someone explain why? But primarily can someone show me practical way how to profile my code and find the answer myself next time ? So I can see where the bottleneck or inefficience is ? i have tried using built-in profilers both in Chrome and Firefox but they didn't help me a much, only showing that my function call takes 1ms of time and nothing really useful. Are there better tools or am I using them wrong ?

My example scenario are 3 nested DIVs. I listen for the event at the top DIV with my delegate handler attached so it catches events also on the nested DIVs. Then I fire click event on the lowest DIV and in JSPerf I measure the time it took to handle the event.

```
// just a simple function for firing "click" event
function clickit(node) {
  var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  event.initEvent('click', false, true);
  event.synthetic = true;
  node.dispatchEvent(event, true);
}

// my very simple implementation of jQuery's delegated .on() function
var F = {
  hasClass:function(el, class_name) {
    return el.className.split(" ").indexOf(class_name) > -1;
  },
  live:function(el, target, event_type, fn){
    if ('class' in target) {
      var live_handler = function(event){
        var target_el = event.target;
        while (target_el != el) {
          if (F.hasClass(target_el, target.class)) return fn.call(target, event);
          target_el = target_el.parentNode;
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
      };
    } else {
      var live_handler = fn;
    }
    el.addEventListener(event_type, live_handler, true);
  }
};
</script>

<div id="test1"><div id="test2" class="target"><div id="test2_2"></div></div></div>
<div id="jq_test1"><div id="jq_test2" class="target"><div id="jq_test2_2"></div></div></div>

<!-- attaching event handlers -->
<script>
var test1 = document.getElementById('test1');
var jq_test2_2 = document.getElementById('jq_test2_2');
F.live(test1, {class:'target'}, 'click', function(event){});
$('#jq_test1').on('click', '.target', function(event){});
</script>
```

[JSPerf for this is available for testing here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-native).

Comment: `className.split` can't be great - matchesSelector for browsers which support it. Plus doesn't just work with class selectors

Comment: Additionally, you should check the [jQuery Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b807aedb7fee321fb3aa5d156a5a256ab0634e2d/src/event.js) and see what it's doing.

Comment: @RGraham Actually, I was measuring my hasClass() with indexOf+split against jQuery's hasClass and my implementation came out ahead of jquery by 33% (see here: http://jsperf.com/myhasclass/2). So I figured that this won't be the bottleneck. But in this question I am really looking for a way how to profile javascript code so I don't have to guess, but be sure where the problem is.

Comment: @RGraham I had surely checked jQuery's and also Zepto.js's sources, they use more complex way and I am looking for really simple JS solution which I can profile and tune to be faster.